# Nenhum dado foi enviado por servidor

Tags: php, classes, require

Ao tentar acessar minha rota *default* no navegador é mostrado o erro do próprio navegador, no caso o Opera:

> **A página de dev.local não está funcionando**
>
> Nenhum dado foi enviado por dev.local

No caso, *dev.local* é meu servidor local. Eu identifiquei onde está dando o erro, mas não sei porque e nem como resolver.

No meu `index.php` tenho o código:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Chamo o núcleo do meu framework
new \LegionLab\Troubadour\Core();
```

No núcleo, o trecho do código que está apresentando o erro é esse:

```
namespace LegionLab\Troubadour;

use LegionLab\Troubadour\Control\Errors;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Collections\Session;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Collections\Settings;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Development\Security;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Routes\Alias;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Routes\Access;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Collections\Saved;
.
.
.    
private function importKernelUtil()
{

    require_once ROOT."settings/alias.php";
    require_once "dispenser.php";

    Session::create();
    require_once ROOT."settings/setups.php";

    // Eis o if que chama um arquivo de migration, é nesse arquivo que está o problema..
    if(Settings::get('deployment'))
        require_once ROOT."settings/database.php";

    Security::errors();

    require_once ROOT."settings/access.php";
}
```

E por fim, aqui esta o `database.php`, responsável por meu *migration*:

```
<?php

use LegionLab\Troubadour\Persistence\Migration;
use LegionLab\Troubadour\Collections\Settings;

$table = new Migration();

$table
    ->database(Settings::get('default_dbname'))
    ->name('authors')
    ->column('id','int', 11, false)
    ->pk('id')
    ->autoincrement('id')
    ->column('name', 'varchar', 50, false)
    ->column('age', 'int', 3)
    ->make();

$table
    ->clear()
    ->database(Settings::get('default_dbname'))
    ->name('books')
    ->column('id','int', 11, false)
    ->pk('id')
    ->autoincrement('id')
    ->column('name', 'varchar', 50, false)
    ->column('price', 'double', 0)
    ->column('author', 'int', 11, false)
    ->addFK('author', array('authors', 'id'))
    ->make();
```

Usando o *PHPStorm* não é apontado nenhum erro, descobri que o erro está no arquivo `database.php`, ao dar `new Migration()`, quando  eu elimino dessa linha até o fim do arquivo o site funciona.

Mas o estranho é que ao colocar um `new Migration()` no meu `index.php` a classe funciona normalmente, e antes funcionava, do nada parou de funcionar. O que pode ser?

Vocês podem testar com o comando do composer:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist legionlab/troubadour-example nome-do-projeto
```

Alterando o arquivo /settings/setups.php com suas configurações do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de tanto tentar, eu fui apaguei a classe `Migration` e criei apenas um `__construct`, então funcionou, daí voltei com o conteúdo da classe toda e acrescentei um `__construct` vazio na classe, assim:

```
public function __construct() {}
```

E assim funcionou, não sei o porque, mas funcionou.